# Ubuntu Server Remote Access - Without Port Forwarding or VPN

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, duck-dns

I have a PC and Virtualbox installed on it.
On the Virtualbox, I have an Ubuntu Servr VM.
I need to access this Ubuntu Server remotely (from any where), but without 'Portforwading' or VPN.

I have account on Duck DNS with the domain "staging17.duckdns.org", and I installed the Duck DNS on my Ubuntu Server VM and it's running correctly and be updated every 5 mins.

When I ping the domain using this command "`ping staging17.duckdns.org`" from another pc, it's pinging.
But when I am trying to access the server using ssh or http like `ssh digizilla@staging17.duckdns.org`, it didn't work.

So, what should I do to be able connect to the server remotely?

Also tried "NGROK" but the free plan allow only listening on one port and If the server is closed for any reason, it regenerate a new link for remote accesss.